# in if condition arraylist .startsWith not correct working

Tags: java

could someone tell me why my if statement with .startsWith is true even though the String (booking) does not start with A? And how to fix it, if possible. thanks in advance!

```
  List<Film> filmList = new ArrayList<>();
        filmList.add(new Film("Batman", "2D", "20:15", "Room 1", "Available"));
        filmList.add(new Film("Batman Returns", "3D", "22:30", "Room 1", "Available"));
        filmList.add(new Film("Batman Returns Again", "3D", "20:15", "Room 2", "Available"));
        filmList.add(new Film("Batman Never Dies", "2D", "23:30", "Room 2", "Booked Out"));

        //printing movie list
        for (Film film : filmList) {
            System.out.println(film.name + " | " + film.quality + " | " + film.time + " | " + film.room + " | " + film.booking);
        }

        //picking movie
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Choose a movie that you want to see!");
        String filmPick = scan.next().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);

        Film pickedfilm = null;
        for (Film film : filmList) {
            if (film.name.equalsIgnoreCase(filmPick) && film.booking.toLowerCase().startsWith("a")) {
                pickedfilm = film;
                System.out.println("Your booking was successfully");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No movie found!");
            }
            break;
        }
```

//class

```
class Film {
    public String name;
    public String quality;
    public String time;
    public String room;
    public String booking;

    public Film(String name, String quali, String time, String room, String booking) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quality = quali;
        this.time = time;
        this.room = room;
        this.booking = booking;
    }
```

Comment: have you debugged your code to check that the values passed are the values you assumed? or added some print statement to check the outcome of that equalsIgnoreCase and ...startsWith?

Comment: i tried debugging it. but my ide did not catch anything

Comment: You need to either use your debugger, or add a print in your if which prints `film.booking`

Comment: And what do you mean "my ide did not catch anything"? The point of using the debugger is so that you can see the state of your program at the point at which it is behaving in a way you don't understand. What was the state when that if statement was being evaluated?

Comment: I'm confused. "available" very much starts with "a". What exactly is your expected behavior?

Comment: Hi, Can you show me `Film` class?

Comment: The value of `booking` is `"Available"` for every film. When you call `toLowerCase()`, the result is `"available"` which begins with "a". What did you *expect* it to be checking against?

Comment: If i choose batman never dies, which is booked out. it will be true regardless, even thought booking then starts with "b"

Comment: @Banguwonderful did you add a breakpoint?

Comment: @Banguwonderful is it checking against "batman never dies" or is it checking against "batman"? Add a breakpoint or additional print statments. See [Manish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70344779/112968) for a potential root cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read nextLine. next() method finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by the input that matches the delimiter pattern.

Whenever you are adding "Batman Never Dies", it read "Batman", and your for-loop will conclude this is present.

replace this line

```
String filmPick = scan.next().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
```

with this:-

```
 String filmPick = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
```